# How to restore to normal to Qtreewidget Pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I just made a program with QTreeWidget.But I want to restore it to normal when I click a button,I mean it should be same as when it started. I learned how to remove the selected section that appears with a blue horizontal line.by

```
mytreeview.clearSelection()
```

check the image[image: the blue tab line]
But if anyone expand the column  width, check the 2nd image[image] , "Type" column width has been increased from 1st picture.Then the question is how can i set it to normal means to my default value shown in picture-1 and imagine someone change the position of "Date Modified" to the place of "Size" column by dragging(position exchanged). Then How can i reset it to normal by pressing a button? This is some fundamental doubts about Qtreewidget so i have no code to write here.
Any help will be appreciated
Thank u

Comment: Plesase provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: actually this is some fundamental doubts about Qtreewidget so i have no code to write.i just need some function to solve my problem.I have edited my post.please check,tell me if u dont understand.@musicamante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect and store the section sizes using [`sectionSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#sectionSize) and restore it with [`resizeSection()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#resizeSections-1).

In order to restore the original *logical* indexes, just check the [`visualIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#visualIndex) and if it doesn't match the logical index then use [`moveSection()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#moveSection).

```
        # ...
        header = self.table.horizontalHeader()
        self.sectionSizes = [header.sectionSize(s) for s in range(header.count())]

    def resetSections(self):
        header = self.table.horizontalHeader()
        for section, size in enumerate(self.sectionSizes):
            if header.visualIndex(section) != section:
                header.moveSection(header.visualIndex(section), section)
            header.resizeSection(section, size)
```

I strongly suggest you to carefully read and *study* the documentation about [QTableWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) (and its inherited classes: [QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) and [QAbstractItemView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html)) along with [QHeaderView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html), as everything you were asking is clearly explained in those pages.

Comment: Thank u! It helped me a lot. Actually the documentation is written for c++ thats why I can't understand it properly.

Comment: @Hacker6914 the official PyQt documentation is very limited and it's not in the interest of their maintainers to complete it, and that's because 95% of it would be just a *copy* of the official Qt documentation. While it might seem a bit overwhelming if you're not experienced with C++, in reality it's much easier than it seems: almost all functions behave exactly in the same way in python and have the same arguments, and the small exceptions can be still found looking for the PyQt related docs or even using `help(class.function)` in the python shell. It's just a matter of habit.

Comment: Just remember two simple aspects: each function is listed with the following syntax: `returnType Class::function(positional arguments, [keyword arguments])`. Each argument is listed as `argumentType, argumentName`, and the "keyword arguments" are exactly the same as in python (so they can usually be omitted). `void` means that the function returns nothing, otherwise if you reimplement that function you *must* return that value type. Note that there are situations for which functions do *not* return data as they actually modify some of its arguments (which is usually not possible in python) ->

Comment: -> In that case, PyQt behaves in a slightly different way than what the C++ documentation suggests. A typical case is `QValidator.validate()`: in C++ it just returns the state, and the `input` and `pos` values are modified "on the fly" if required (as C++ allows to send a *reference* to a variable). In PyQt that function actually returns all arguments: the state, the input and the position, so that it's possible to change those values and return them as required by Qt.